# How to make a DNS server on Ubuntu server VM that accesible from hosts

Tags: server, dns, virtualization

i want to make a DNS server on Ubuntu Server on VM that can be accessed from host (windows). i already make a DNS server but i dont know how to make it so it can be accessed from host.

FYI :

Ubuntu Server 18.04.3

VMBox 6.0

BIND9

Answer (score 0):

Exposing a VM to your network requires [Port Forwarding and NAT](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-forward-ports-through-a-linux-gateway-with-iptables). In this case, over port 53/TCP using your system's firewall (iptables on Linux in most cases, On windows, you can use [netsh](http://woshub.com/port-forwarding-in-windows/) to the same effect).

For your VM to be able to reach the internet, your hypervisor (VMBox) sets this up in one direction for you so that your VM's can share your internet connection, but for outside hosts to reach the VM, you must manually configure it the other way, or set up a [bridge](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_bridged) which will dedicate an entire interface to the VM. This is much easier to set up, but does not allow connection sharing and fully exposes your VM as though it were a real machine on your network, not just a DNS server.

[NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) stands for Network Address Translation. It means that your host (physical machine) will recieve network packets, the firewall will scan them and determine whether or not they are destined to another network your host has access to (the "virtual" network your VM is connected to), and rather than allowing a direct connection to be established it will "stand in" for the outside host and use its own IP address, acting as a "middle-man". This allows you to filter down what connections can be made with hosts on an internal network, in this case ensuring that only DNS requests over the correct port reach the DNS server.

On the VM itself, you'll also need to edit its own firewall to ensure it is accepting connections on the desired port. Ubuntu has [UFW](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-setup-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-18-04/) (Uncomplicated FireWall), but for a simple operation like opening a port you can just run
`iptables -I INPUT 1 -j ACCEPT -p tcp --dport 53`
(just make sure you [save](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Saving_Iptables_Firewall_Rules_Permanently) your rules or they won't persist through a reboot).

Comment: You also need to port forward udp/53 which is the default for DNS queries.